# C for loop syntax understanding

Tags: c++, c

I am doing a program for tic-tac-toe and i have a line with

```
for ( count = 1; count < 10 && winner == 0; count++ );
```

I referred to other programs and came up with this.

And I'm not very sure of what the entire line means. I have searched up online but I dont understand the meaning of initialization statement `( count = 1 )` and the test expression. And also want to clarify, `count++` means increase `count` right?

Comment: You can replace the for loop with this while loop: `count = 1; while (count < 10 && winner == 0) { count++; }`. Read more https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know this, then it's time to start reading your beginner's C text book.

Comment: I'd like to point out that a semicolon `;` directly after the condition brackets `(` `)` is almost never correct. It is only very rarely that the programmer means to do that. A compiler will probably warn you for it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the structure of a for loop:

```
for ( init-statement; condition; iteration_expression) statement;
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), a for loop does the following:

> Executes init-statement once, then executes statement and iteration_expression repeatedly, until the value of condition becomes false. The test takes place before each iteration.

For your case:

- `init statement`: at the beginning `count` is initialized to `1`
- `condition`:  check if `count` is less than `10` and you don't have a `winner` yet
- `iteration_expression`: `cout++` increases `count` by 1
- `statement`: you haven't provided that, but it will be executed until the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of for loop is

```
for(initialization; condition; increment/decrement){
statement;
}
```

1. initialization:
   Before we start looping, we will initialize the variable to certain value.
   In this case, you are initializing 'count' variable to 1
2. Condition:
   In condition part, To stop the loop at certain point you have to provide some conditions.
   In this case, condition is 'count<10 && winner==0'. Note that, you are using And(&&) operation so, loop will stop only after both of the conditions are satisfied.
3. increment/decrement:
   Based on the problem, you can choose to increment or decrement the loop variable('count'). In this case, count++ means you are incrementing the count by 1 after each iteration.

Comment: In reality there is no C syntactic rules indicate you have to perform init then cond then increment. It can be any valid statement anywhere. It is just the usual way to do, however I saw lot's of `while` loop wrote like this : `for(;;){statement;}` which work perfectly well.

Comment: yes, you are right, I just mention the common way of for loop

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
for (initialize;condition;increment/decrement)
```

`for` loop means

1. you initialize the variable
2. you apply a condition to stop the `for` loop
3. you execute a single time the loop body (if the condition satisfied)
4. then you increase or decrease the value of that variable and go to step 2